# S3Slider jQuery Stop After One Rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, slider

I'm using an S3Slider on WordPress.  I'd like it to stop after one rotation, but can't seem to figure out the setting.

The following code is used in the slider.js file.  Right now it's live at http://beaconwc.com on the frontpage, would like it to show the two slides and then stop until the user refreshes the page.

```
(function($){  

    $.fn.s3Slider = function(vars) {       

        var element     = this;
        var timeOut     = (vars.timeOut != undefined) ? vars.timeOut : 4000;
        var current     = null;
        var timeOutFn   = null;
        var faderStat   = true;
        var mOver       = false;
         var capOpacity  = vars.captionOpacity || .7;
        var items       = $("#" + element[0].id + "Content ." + element[0].id + "Image");
        var itemsSpan   = $("#" + element[0].id + "Content ." + element[0].id + "Image div");

        itemsSpan.css({
            'opacity': capOpacity,
            'display': 'none'
        });

        items.each(function(i) {

            $(items[i]).mouseover(function() {
               mOver = true;
            });

            $(items[i]).mouseout(function() {
                mOver   = false;
                fadeElement(true);
            });

        });

        var fadeElement = function(isMouseOut) {
            var thisTimeOut = (isMouseOut) ? (timeOut/2) : timeOut;
            thisTimeOut = (faderStat) ? 10 : thisTimeOut;
            if(items.length > 0) {
                timeOutFn = setTimeout(makeSlider, thisTimeOut);
            } else {
                console.log("Poof..");
            }
        }

        var makeSlider = function() {
            current = (current != null) ? current : items[(items.length-1)];
            var currNo      = jQuery.inArray(current, items) + 1
            currNo = (currNo == items.length) ? 0 : (currNo - 1);
            var newMargin   = $(element).width() * currNo;
            if(faderStat == true) {
                if(!mOver) {
                    $(items[currNo]).fadeIn((timeOut/6), function() {
                        if($(itemsSpan[currNo]).css('bottom') == 0) {
                            $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideUp((timeOut/6), function() {
                                faderStat = false;
                                current = items[currNo];
                                if(!mOver) {
                                    fadeElement(false);
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideDown((timeOut/6), function() {
                                faderStat = false;
                                current = items[currNo];
                                if(!mOver) {
                                    fadeElement(false);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                if(!mOver) {
                    if($(itemsSpan[currNo]).css('bottom') == 0) {
                        $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideDown((timeOut/6), function() {
                            $(items[currNo]).fadeOut((timeOut/6), function() {
                                faderStat = true;
                                current = items[(currNo+1)];
                                if(!mOver) {
                                    fadeElement(false);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    } else {
                        $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideUp((timeOut/6), function() {
                        $(items[currNo]).fadeOut((timeOut/6), function() {
                                faderStat = true;
                                current = items[(currNo+1)];
                                if(!mOver) {
                                    fadeElement(false);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        makeSlider();

    };  

})(jQuery);
```

Thanks!

Source
http://www.serie3.info/s3slider/